# 3-D engines in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, 3d

I just wanted  to know if there are
3-D engines available for flex other
than PaperVision?

Just out of curosity....

Answer (score 1):

[Sandy3D](http://www.flashsandy.org/)

[Away3D](http://away3d.com/)

These are both mature engines at this point that have seen use in commercial work.

Comment: Use Away3D. It's not really a Flex engine though -- it's ActionScript